# How do I make a subway twink?

Tags: anarchy-online

Planning to play Anarchy Online after a long time; and want to do something I never got around to earlier - make a twink to kill Abmouth.

Some limitations or conditions of what I want to do:

- Froob! No perks :)
- Not super rich, no GA etc.
- Self-buffed only if at all possible
- I prefer Neutral; but can go for Omni or Clan if sided equipment is essential
- Any profession is fine
- I don't need 100% success rate, I do understand it will be harder without outside buffs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use an enforcer/doc... get neleb's rod ....put on some 83-100 imps, best carb armor or cas if you can find it, but I would go carb for the ncu, have a friend camp GOT or if you can't get gta go with exarch.... you should own subway.

Comment: Could you make your answer with a better format? it's kind hard to understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Michel I play Anarchy and I understand it perfectly.

Comment: @leetfan Sorry, but I don't. And I think +9 person think the same (that could be better formatted). +isthisbetter made a good edit, anyway.

Comment: @Michel An answer must not cater towards people that don't play the game and someone who plays it, knows what GOT, Carb and NCU is.

Comment: @leetfan I wasn't talking about the nomenclature... but whatever, if you want to discuss it, you can do it on the [CHAT](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), so the comment area doesn't lost focus.